# Start Nautilus from Firefox download

Tags: firefox, nautilus

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 I have the latest Firefox installed. When i download a file from the internet. It ends up in the download folder. And Firefox show list of downloaded files. There is a "button" for each file, saying "Show File in Folder" (translated from danish). When clicking this button the mouse cursor turns into a spinner but that's all. I have to use the taskbar's Nautilus button and browse to download folder. I did actually expect this to be fixed. But now it's a year ago I installed 22.04 and it still doesn't work.
I then assume that it might only be me that see this problem, since none has complained. Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Snap version of Firefox, try the deb version. In the deb version this option works fine.

To install the deb version of Firefox, follow the steps below (from [Archisman Panigrahi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/618353) in [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)):

1. Uninstall Firefox:

   ```
   sudo snap remove firefox
   ```
2. Add the Firefox PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
   ```
3. Run the following command (copy and paste it as a whole, not line by line):

   ```
   echo '
   Package: *
   Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
   ```
4. Run the following command (copy and paste it as a whole, not line by line):

   ```
   echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
   ```
5. Reinstall Firefox:

   ```
   sudo apt install firefox
   ```